What is the Best Way to Seal the Space Between an External Door and the Door Jamb?
I have two outward opening external doors that are a refuge for lizards and other pests that often scurry inside my home when the doors are opened. I also have an issue with rain coming through those spaces and puddling inside the threshold. I am also considering getting air conditioning to cool the interior. The space varies between 2 mm and 6 mm (0.8 inch and 0.25 inch). What is the best way to seal the door and jamb in that scenario?
        

Usually use weather stripping to close gaps around a door.

There are multiple types of weatherstriping and door sweeps for the bottom.  What would work best for you is dependant on design factors we do not know about.  A few pics of the door and jamb and threshold would be helpful in giving more specific advice.

@RMDman, please see pics. There is existing stripping around the sides and top that seems to be glued on but I not sure how well it is still sealing. There is also a degraded door sweep that I am unsure how it is attached.

There are many types of weather stripping to seal around a door. The following are examples, for illustration only.

Foam
Felt
Plastic
Metal
Metal and rubber or plastic

All help seal a door for air conditioning, but as to which works best to discourage lizards, ask your neighbors. (On the other hand, geckos, in particular, do make effective insect traps!)
Also, a door sweep on the bottom will brush away critters lingering on the threshold, as well as helping seal the door for air conditioning.

The Plastic and Metal and rubber or plastic options you suggested seem like they would work well to seal from the inside as the existing stripping is inflexible and squashed in places. Can the Foam strips be used to seal the gap between the door and the jamb? I am not even sure if I using the word jamb correctly, what I am referring to is the wood frame around the sides and top that be clearly seen in the first four pics.

@Hangout4668, all are effective where properly installed. As for directions, some of those links have videos to show installation of their product, and see more at https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=install+weatherstripping+around+door . Your question is reasonable and understandable, and there are instructions on the web.
